# how can I copy guides from one artboard to another

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator to lay out a multi-page pdf, I've set up some guides on an artboard and I'd like other artboards to have the same guides. Can I copy them over?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

View > Guides > Unlock Guides. Then they're like any other vector objects, so you can select, copy, and paste-in-place on your other artboards.

Comment: To expound upon this, once unlocked they _can_ then be grouped and aligned to the artboard. This was super helpful when mine got messed up and I needed to bring over the originals from my template and recenter them. Thanks @Ike!